# Vite With Express and React multi gateway

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, vite, vite-reactjs

I'm trying to get a high performance architecture with a Vite + Express + React setup.

I know that many browsers limit parallel network requests to a single IP.

**My goal:** is to implement an architecture that spreads out the type of requests to different servers to maximize throughput to the client. I already know that my clients have the resources to run such high throughput (CPU & network wise).
Api requests go to API.
JS requests go to Vite dev server.
assets go to another server.

**Requirements:**

- Frontend in react.
- Backend in express (API).
- Backend uses cookies (passport).
- A dynamic approach that's easy to change / duplicate for more environments.
- Vite:

  - Client has a direct connection to vite dev server for integrated features (fast HMR and more)
  - When in prod mode, should fetch html/js/css/assets from the different servers (similar to a CDN, but i host all the servers my self)

**I've tried** using vite's [backend-integration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html). Fetching initial GET "/" from my API to create a cookie, it then retrieves the html file from vite dev server and returns it. The problem is that chrome keeps fetching html/js/assets from the api and not directly from vite dev server. I added this to vite.config `{ server: { origin: 'http://localhost:5173' } }`. I've tried all sorts of variations but couldn't get it to work properly.